# Iqueryable can't call Include method

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, entity, iqueryable

I was using `IQueryable` and `Reflection` to select tables dynamically :

```
IQueryable<object> query = typeof(GWork).GetProperty(tblName).GetValue(context, null) as IQueryable<object>;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(relations) && query != null)
{
    relatedEntities = relations.Split(','); 

    foreach (string relatedEntity in relatedEntities)
    {
        query.Include(relatedEntity);                        
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error : IQueryable does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' althought I have included `System.Data.Entity`

I tried to cast the `IQueryable<object>` to `ObjectQuery<object>` but the conversion will result in `null` values

Is this a `.Net Framework` version problem? My project is currently using version 4.0

Any advices are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a compilation error because it cannot validate statically that such method exists, besides, Include() is an extension method. You must reference the namespace where this method belongs.

Manage to include this on top of file:

```
using System.Data.Entity
```

Comment: Thanks but I did include it, it's in my question

Comment: And is EntityFramework.dll referenced in your project?

Comment: Also, remeber that Include() returns a new Queryable<>. It does not  modify the original object.

Comment: Perfect! I wasn't refrencing EntityFramework in my project. How silly! Thanks alot!